# Nuxt-Apollo - Network error: Server response was missing for query 'FILTERED_PRODUCT'

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, orchardcms, apollo-client, graphiql

I am using Apollo on my Nuxt project to query the server, which is servered on Orchard-Core.
Since now I had only simple queries and it was very simple to figure out how to use them, but now I am trying to filter some informations in the queries, with bad results.

**Code**

Here is some code which I am using:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="search">search "Bare Van-gogh"</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const FILTERED_PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
  query FILTERED_PRODUCTS ($description: String!) {
    product (filter: { description: $description }) {
      contentItemId
      displayText
      description
      badge
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      descriptionText: 'Van-gogh',
      searchResults: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async search() {
      const res = await this.$apollo.query({
        query: FILTERED_PRODUCT_QUERY,
        variables: {
          description: this.descriptionText
        }
      })

      if (res) {
        const { results } = res.data.product
        this.searchResults = results
        alert(this.searchResults[0])
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In my database I have 4 products and one of them has as descriptions "Van-gogh", I would like to show that description in the alert, but instead I get a error page:

[image]

**Network Tab**

Here you can see what the Network tab return me:

Headers:
[image]

Preview:
[image]

Response:
[image]

**Error messages**

Here you can see the error messages I get from Orchard-Core side when I try to run the queries:

If I am using "where" I get an error on "description" field:
[image]

If I am using "filter" I get an error directly on filter argument:
[image]

Is there someone that can help me and suggest me how to make it works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to find where the error is coming from? Is it in your frontend client side call? (check the network tab) Or in the backend, that it cannot find it somehow?

Comment: I will edit my question with the network status. I guest that the server is not configured to accept the filter argument, I've also tried with "where: { description: $description }", but it is still not working.

Comment: To debug faster, use the Graphql Playground!

Comment: @kissu, I can debug my queries directly from the Orchard-Core side, I will update the main question with the results of my query tryings.